# View Mac app files like iOS apps using iFunBox

Tags: macos, filesystem

I have some apps installed on my iMac and would want to view the contents of the app using iFunBox. I am having great difficulty doing so. I can view the contents of apps on my iPhone using iFunBox but can't seem to do same for apps on my iMac.

Do you know if I can do this using iFunBox or what alternatives do can you suggest?

Comment: FYI: Apple changed security settings in iOS 8.3 (in 2015) that prevent file managers and transfer utilities such as iFunBox, iTools, iExplorer, iBackupBot and PhoneView from gaining access to app sandboxed directories. Access may be possible if the app has expressly enabled "iTunes File Sharing".

Answer (score 6):

You don't need any software for this.
Simply right-click the app bundle and select **Show Package Contents**.

[image]

---

To view app *data*, look in ~/Library/Application Support and ~/Library/Preferences
<sup>~ is the home folder, accessible through Finder. ~/Library is hidden — use the Finder's Go menu (hold ⌥).</sup>

Comment: Thanks truthfully, was actually trying to delete "documents" folder on an app. when i select "show package contents" i don't see the files as i do on my iPhone when using ifunbox

Comment: @user73333 Indeed, you won't since Show Package Contents is for the app itself, not any data. For the app data, see the second part to my answer.

Comment: sorry for being a pester. i just could not find it. Any other option?

Comment: @user73333 Unlike iOS, there is no Documents folder that holds all the documents. Data is stored wherever you save it from the save dialog (your documents folder, desktop, etc). Data such as preferences are stored in a plist in ~/Library/Preferences named the bundle identifier.